# Symfony 6 App\Entity\Question object not found by the @ParamConverter annotation

Tags: symfony, routes

I try to make answers for question.

Here is my AnswerController:

```
#[Route('/{slug}/{name}/answer/{question}', name: 'answer_question')]
public function answer(Question $q, QuestionRepository $questionRepository, string $question, Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, string $slug, string $name, AnswerRepository $answerRepository): Response
{
    $questions = $questionRepository->findOneBySlug($question);

    $answers = $answerRepository->findAnswers($question);

    $form = $this->createForm(AnswerType::class);

    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $data = $form->getData();

        $answer = new Answer();
        $answer->setContent($data->getContent());
        $answer->setAnsweredAt(new \DateTime);
        $answer->setQuestion($q);

        $entityManager->persist($answer);
        $entityManager->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('show_question', [
            'slug' => $slug,
            'name' => $name,
            'question' => $question,
        ]);
    }

    return $this->render('answer/index.html.twig', [
        'questions' => $questions,
        'answers' => $answers,
        'answer' =>  $form->createView(),
    ]);
}
```

I have problem with

App\Entity\Question object not found by the @ParamConverter annotation

EDIT:

Still I have a little problem with wildcards,
for example when i put address "/audi-a3/8v/answer/question" it's ok, but when i put "/audi-a4/8v/answer/question" ( there isn't audi-a4 with model 8v but this address gives me correct page for "8V" model. It doesn't match ).
Can someone explain me how to do it right?

Comment: Where do you try to add "Question $question" ? as parameter of  "answer" function of AnswerController ?

Comment: Yes. "Question $q". I have a Question and I want to post an Answer related to this Question. Without Question object I can post an Answer without any relation to the Question.

Comment: Can you try to add like this `Question $question` instead of just `$q` and give me the result

Comment: I removed "string $question" and changed "Question $q" to "Question $question" and I got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I did some changes in AnswerController and now it's working.

Set ParamConverter manually.

```
#[Route('/{car}/{name}/answer/{slug}', name: 'answer_question')]
#[ParamConverter('question', class: Question::class, options: ['mapping' => ['slug' => 'slug']])]
public function answer(Question $question, QuestionRepository $questionRepository, Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, string $slug, string $name, string $car, AnswerRepository $answerRepository): Response
{
    $questions = $questionRepository->findOneBySlug($slug);

    $answers = $answerRepository->findAnswers($slug);

    $form = $this->createForm(AnswerType::class);

    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $data = $form->getData();

        $answer = new Answer();
        $answer->setContent($data->getContent());
        $answer->setAnsweredAt(new \DateTime);
        $answer->setQuestion($question);

        $entityManager->persist($answer);
        $entityManager->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('show_question', [
            'slug' => $slug,
            'name' => $name,
            'car' => $car,
        ]);
    }

    return $this->render('answer/index.html.twig', [
        'questions' => $questions,
        'answers' => $answers,
        'answer' =>  $form->createView(),
    ]);
}
```